# php update only columns for which variables are not null

Tags: php

I am fairly new in php.I have following php script:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

     $query = "UPDATE customer
     SET eidosmetaf1=:e1 , weight1=:w1 , startNomos1=:sn1 , startPoli1=:sc1 , start_lat=:slat1 , start_lng=:slng1 ,
     finalNomos1=:fn1 , finalpoli1=:fc1 , final_lat=:flat1 , final_lng=:flng1 , depDate1=:dD1 , depTime1=:dT1 ,
     specialservices1=:ex1 , comments1=:c1
     WHERE username1=:un1 and weight1=:w1_old and comments1=:c1_old";       

    $query_params = array(
    ':un1' => $_POST['username1'],
    ':e1' => $_POST['eidosmetaf1'],
    ':w1' => $_POST['weight1'],
    ':sn1' => $_POST['startNomos1'],
    ':sc1' => $_POST['startPoli1'],
    ':slat1' => $_POST['start_lat'],
    ':slng1' => $_POST['start_lng'],
    ':fn1' => $_POST['finalNomos1'],
    ':fc1' => $_POST['finalpoli1'],
    ':flat1' => $_POST['final_lat'],
    ':flng1' => $_POST['final_lng'],
    ':dD1' => $_POST['depDate1'],
    ':dT1' => $_POST['depTime1'],
    ':ex1' => $_POST['specialservices1'],
    ':c1' => $_POST['comments1'],
     ':w1_old' => $_POST['weight_old'],
     ':c1_old' => $_POST['comments2_old']       
);    

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }    

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "..................!";
    echo json_encode($response); 


?>
```

But some times $_POST['xxxxxx'] variables are empty or null. How can i update only those columns for which the corresponding variables are not null or empty; Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be the following:

1. Define a $query variable with the start of the query
2. Check if the variable is set, if yes, add it to the query string and set the parameter

---

```
<?
$query = "UPDATE customer SET ";
if(isset($_POST['var1'])){
  $stmt->bindParam(":v", $_POST['var1']);
  $query .= "var1 = :v";
}
?>
```